# Why does the Rambam require repentance, and not just more good deeds, before Yom Kippur?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, yom-kippur, theology, hashkafah-philosophy

The Rambam says if someone's virtues-vs-sins balance is even as of Rosh Hashanah, their verdict happens on yom kippur.  If they did teshuva in those ten days, they get a pass; if not, they don't.

Question is, why teshuva necessarily?  Just do lots more good deeds in that period!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many answers given.

- The even balance was for 5770; any further good deeds are already on the 5771 sheet.  Only way to fix the 5770 sheet is to regret and repent wrongdoings from 5770.  (This likely ties in with [a view attributed to R' Ahron Kotler discussed here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2929/buying-arba-minnim/2932#2932).)

---

- The season is so supportive of repentance (dirshu Hashem behimatz'o), that to *not* repent is itself a mega-wrongdoing that would outweigh a lot of good.

Comment: I don't really see how answer #1 ties in with RAK's practice with regard to buying Arba Minim. But it happens to be that I've heard this answer in the name of RAK! (From R' Akiva Tatz, I think.)

Comment: Answer #2 is from R' Itzele Petterburger, one of the top talmidim of R' Yisrael Salanter.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I'd say it follows from answer #1 that lulav-buying does absolutely nothing for your 5770 balance; hence, let lulav-buying wait a few more days (5771 either way), and spend more time with introspection on your 5770 faults.

Comment: I hear what you're saying...